# How to read json from google drive with rest api

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I have created some Json file that contains shop's objects and i want to store it on Google drive and read it with Retrofit.

Currently, I can't store it in local memory or in-app.
Also, there is no server side yet, so it needs to be stored somewhere that Retrofit can access.
If you have any other ideas, I'd be more than happy to hear.

I make the link public to anyone, and here is my .json file:

```
{
  "shop": [
    {
      "shopName": "Renuar",
      "shopID": "1000",
      "isPaid": "false",
      "branches": [
        {
          "branchName": "Branch 1",
          "branchPhone": "039599559",
          "openingTime": "09:00",
          "closingTime": "21:00",
          "branchLat": "32.000",
          "branchLon": "35.000",
          "branchAddressNote": "Grand Canyon"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "shopName": "Castro",
      "shopID": "1000",
      "isPaid": "false",
      "branches": [
        {
          "branchName": "Branch 1",
          "branchPhone": "039599559",
          "openingTime": "09:00",
          "closingTime": "21:00",
          "branchLat": "32.000",
          "branchLon": "35.000",
          "branchAddressNote": "Grand Canyon"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried the next steps but it's not work for me.

```
public interface ApiService {
        @GET("file/d/1-lsBIzI7Y5uCg8bG_531o49Dcu6E2RdH/view?usp=sharing")
        Call<ShopsResponse> getAllShops();
    }

    public static class RetrofitInstance{
        public static Retrofit retrofit = null;
        private static final String BASE_URL = "https://drive.google.com/";

        public static ApiService getApiService(){
            if (retrofit == null){

                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .setLenient()
                        .create();

                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                        .build();
            }
            return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
        }

    }

ApiService apiService = RetrofitInstance.getApiService();
        apiService.getAllShops().enqueue(new Callback<ShopsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ShopsResponse> call, Response<ShopsResponse> response) {
                ShopsResponse response1 = response.body();
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+response1.getShop().size());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ShopsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

That what i receive in logcat:

```
D/myDebug: onResponse: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with your pojo objects. It should be like this according to your response

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Branch {

@SerializedName("branchName")
@Expose
private String branchName;
@SerializedName("branchPhone")
@Expose
private String branchPhone;
@SerializedName("openingTime")
@Expose
private String openingTime;
@SerializedName("closingTime")
@Expose
private String closingTime;
@SerializedName("branchLat")
@Expose
private String branchLat;
@SerializedName("branchLon")
@Expose
private String branchLon;
@SerializedName("branchAddressNote")
@Expose
private String branchAddressNote;

public String getBranchName() {
return branchName;
}

public void setBranchName(String branchName) {
this.branchName = branchName;
}

public String getBranchPhone() {
return branchPhone;
}

public void setBranchPhone(String branchPhone) {
this.branchPhone = branchPhone;
}

public String getOpeningTime() {
return openingTime;
}

public void setOpeningTime(String openingTime) {
this.openingTime = openingTime;
}

public String getClosingTime() {
return closingTime;
}

public void setClosingTime(String closingTime) {
this.closingTime = closingTime;
}

public String getBranchLat() {
return branchLat;
}

public void setBranchLat(String branchLat) {
this.branchLat = branchLat;
}

public String getBranchLon() {
return branchLon;
}

public void setBranchLon(String branchLon) {
this.branchLon = branchLon;
}

public String getBranchAddressNote() {
return branchAddressNote;
}

public void setBranchAddressNote(String branchAddressNote) {
this.branchAddressNote = branchAddressNote;
}

}




package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("shop")
@Expose
private List<Shop> shop = null;

public List<Shop> getShop() {
return shop;
}

public void setShop(List<Shop> shop) {
this.shop = shop;
}

}




package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Shop {

@SerializedName("shopName")
@Expose
private String shopName;
@SerializedName("shopID")
@Expose
private String shopID;
@SerializedName("isPaid")
@Expose
private String isPaid;
@SerializedName("branches")
@Expose
private List<Branch> branches = null;

public String getShopName() {
return shopName;
}

public void setShopName(String shopName) {
this.shopName = shopName;
}

public String getShopID() {
return shopID;
}

public void setShopID(String shopID) {
this.shopID = shopID;
}

public String getIsPaid() {
return isPaid;
}

public void setIsPaid(String isPaid) {
this.isPaid = isPaid;
}

public List<Branch> getBranches() {
return branches;
}

public void setBranches(List<Branch> branches) {
this.branches = branches;
}

}
```

Comment: I have the same pojo classes.